# How can I narrow down the type of a function argument without a variable

Tags: typescript

I have a function that accepts `any` as parameter:

```
declare function postMessage(message: any): void;
```

I'm trying to call it with an object of certain type as follows:

```
interface NumMsg {type: 'num'; num: number}
interface StrMsg {type: 'str'; str: string}

type Msg = NumMsg | StrMsg;

postMessage({type: 'num', num: 42} as Msg);
postMessage({type: 'str', str: 'Hello World!'} as Msg);
```

It kind of works but it makes some of the required properties optional - it builds successfully without any errors:

```
// Works fine / fails to build:
postMessage({type: 'num', 'str': 'Hello world!'} as Msg);
postMessage({type: 'str', 'num': 42} as Msg);

// Doesn't work fine / build without errors:
postMessage({});
postMessage({type: 'str'} as Msg);
postMessage({type: 'num'} as Msg);
```

I can solve that issue by defining it as a variable first:

```
let msg1: Msg = {};
let msg2: Msg = {type: 'str'};
let msg3: Msg = {type: 'num'};
```

Can I make this work without defining any variables?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're hoping for. Maybe make the type of `message` _generic_ in `postMessage`, rather than just `any`, so you can do `postMessage<Msg>({ ... })`?

Comment: I'm trying to send a message to a worker, but I want to make sure that I pass all required properties. I was trying to avoid extending DOM's types by either adding a new one or wrapping `postMessage` in a separate function, e.g. `postTypedMessage<Type>(...)`.

Comment: I think you should read about excess property checks https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks
It will be much clearer for you why extra variable was build without any errors

Comment: I'd willing to bet that you will find here some workarounds https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I decided to add an overload to the said function: ()

```
declare function postMessage<T>(message: T): void;
```

Credits to [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe).

Now I have the following:

```
declare function postMessage(message: any): void;
declare function postMessage<T>(message: T): void;
```

It works even though the former signature is/seems more general.

Now I can do the following without any issues:

```
postMessage<Msg>({type: 'num', 'str': 'Hello world!'});
postMessage<Msg>({type: 'str', 'num': 42});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you can't change the type of `postMessage` (for instance, that it's the `postMessage` defined in the web platform or similar).

I'd solve this by having a wrapper function, not a variable, and not using `postMessage` directly at all:

```typescript
function postMsg(message: NumMsg | StrMsg) {
    postMessage(message);
}
```

(But with a better function name. :-) )

Then these work:

```typescript
postMsg({type: "num", num: 42});
postMsg({type: "str", str: "Hellow world!"});
```

...and these cause errors as desired:

```typescript
postMsg({});
postMsg({type: "str"});
postMsg({type: "num"});
postMsg({type: "num", "str": "Hello world!"});
postMsg({type: "str", "num": 42});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAccBnDAWRGOKgHMQAKAW0uroC54pUBPASg4BuOLMADcAKHFZUGEDERQwCAHLJGZYjXgBvDNwIgOAIlRqjo+KcYcrAIzkBfKTLkKl8AMoYYGrbv2G8EakMObwIRwh0jRO4ijo2HiEJOSaTCy0garqmvAAPp7evrw64vDlyaQUVJnpNXS8ErEA9M3wACoAFpQIAO44MADWbOJEVWn+BsZWRgA0lmocACwATA6Noym+9JOBwd5z4d7GABIgEBA4vfD9MBDAAIRG6xLirR3dxAhgUMhf8HIYANiCMxqkaDsXptxhDdsYQs8NmDtnCgjMociJnopmizPN9qFTudLjcBvcnhitliAvCDviZss1hsgA)

---

If you **can** change the types of `postMessage`, just do it directly:

```typescript
declare function postMessage(message: NumMsg | StrMsg): void;
```

Comment: > I'm assuming you can't change the type of `postMessage` (for instance, that it's the `postMessage` defined in the web platform or similar).  
  
Kind of... I gave a dumbed down version of `postMessage` of a regular web page for simplicity. What I'm actually fighting is [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/cd3823ed9280785bb0d37de829094eaefe97360a/types/chrome/index.d.ts#L6447-L6485) from Chrome's extensions APIs. It has many overloads and it's tricky to wrap.

Comment: I'd be easier to just call the identity function for each object literal:  

```ts
function identity<T>(val: T): T {
  return val;
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(identity<Msg>({type: 'str'}));
```
I'd want to avoid such workarounds as they are ugly.

Comment: @dewakaputo - I wouldn't use that `identity` function either. :-) The point of `postMsg` above is that it's specific to messages. It says something about what it's doing.